# Symfony3 Fetching data from entities with ManyToMany association

Tags: symfony, doctrine, associations

I have a problem with ManyToMany association. I cant't figure out how to fetch data from database.
I have 2 entities - Teacher and Subject.

Class Subject

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Teacher", mappedBy="subjects")
 */
private $teachers;


public function __construct() {

    $this->teachers = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Add teacher
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Teacher $teacher
 *
 * @return Subject
 */
public function addTeacher(\AppBundle\Entity\Teacher $teacher)
{
    $this->teachers[] = $teacher;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove teacher
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Teacher $teacher
 */
public function removeTeacher(\AppBundle\Entity\Teacher $teacher)
{
    $this->teachers->removeElement($teacher);
}

/**
 * Get teachers
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getTeachers()
{
    return $this->teachers;
}
```

And entity Teacher

Class Teacher

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Subject", inversedBy="teachers")
 */
private $subjects;

public function __construct()
    {
        $this->subjects = new ArrayCollection();
    }

/**
 * Add subject
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Subject $subject
 *
 * @return Teacher
 */
public function addSubject(\AppBundle\Entity\Subject $subject)
{
    $this->subjects[] = $subject;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove subject
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Subject $subject
 */
public function removeSubject(\AppBundle\Entity\Subject $subject)
{
    $this->subjects->removeElement($subject);
}

/**
 * Get subjects
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getSubjects()
{
    return $this->subjects;
}
```

All i want to do is fetch all information from Teacher + Subjects associated with them.

How should looks like my controller to do this?

I try do this by

```
   $teacher = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Teacher::class)->findAll();

    return $this->render('admin/adminDashboard.html.twig', [
                'teachers' => $teacher]);
```

But i still got errors

Comment: what errors do you get?

Comment: I put teacher into foreach loop where i refer to getSubjects method (like @domagoj03 advised me) and in Twig I dump(teacher), when I do this I don't have any more errors but ArrayCollection of Subjects is empty https://i.imgur.com/mptIJ79.jpg

And im sure i have some association in my table Teacher_Subject

Comment: And the error i got when i try to render templeate with {{ teacher.subjects }} is "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection could not be converted to string").

Comment: assuming you changed the name `$teacher` to `$teachers`, pass it to your template and there try this `{% for t in teachers %}{{dump(t.subjects.count)}}{% endfor %}`. that should print a line per teacher with the number of subjects in each

Comment: Yup, it works. Like you said, i have three lines (i have 3 teachers in db) and in each line i have number 1 (i have 3 subjects. each one related to each teacher)

Comment: But i still have issue with fetching it without dump()

Answer (score 0):

First, my advice is to change your $teacher variable to $teachers as 
findAll() method returns an array so you have to iterate through it. In your controller:

```
foreach($teachers as $teacher) { // Here you have $teacher and you can do $teacher->getSubjects() }
```

In your twig template:

```
{% for teacher in teachers %}
  {{ dump(teacher) }}
{% endfor %}
```

If that doesnt work, let us know what kind of errors do you get.
This is all assuming that you have entries inside your database, or from wherever you're fetching your entities.

Comment: That could mean either you have no records of subjects associated with the mentioned group of teachers or there's something wrong with your associations. Without more clues, I can't help any more than this.

Answer (score 0):

if `{% for t in teachers %}{{dump(t.subjects.count)}}{% endfor %}` worked, it means the data is there.

If you mean `{{teacher.subjects}}` throws error: *An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection could not be converted to string*. Well in case you have never seen this error before, take a close read:

*Object of class Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection* refers to `subjects`, which as a collection that it is, cannot be just thrown into an html tag like a string.

Depends on how you want to present your data but the very basics would be:

```
{% for t in teachers %}
    <tr>
    {% for s in t.subjects %}
        <td>s.getName</td>
     {% endfor %}
    </tr>
 {% endfor %}
```

assuming `subject` entity has a property `name` and a getter for it. Hope you get the gist.

let me know

Comment: It finally works! Thank you very much for help and your time!

Comment: @miguelsantos69 anytime!